# How do you disable the new invert screen colors on/ off notification in MacOS Big Sur?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, accessibility

I've been using the `control + option + command + 8` shortcut for some time to help me see text on websites that bother my eyes (this keyboard shortcut is enabled from the accessibility of the keyboard shortcut widget found in system preferences).

After updating to MacOS Big Sur, a large window now fades into the screen after I activate this shortcut which obscures the screen for several seconds until it's fade in and out animations complete.  Is there a way to disable the notification window so that I can work on my macbook uninterrupted like before?

Comment: Does it really obscure the screen for several seconds? It's a small rectangle in the middle of the display, and lasts for precisely 1 second here.

Comment: Use a stopwatch @benwiggy, it takes 2 seconds for the animations to complete after triggering the combo.  I can't speak to how large your monitor is or what the scaling properties are of the window, but I see a large window that is in the middle of the screen which is where text usually is when people are reading.  It's 600 x 600px for my macbook pro and so, for instance, obscures the OP of this thread when displayed.

Comment: @Ninjaxor, same, I've been using this for years... surprise at every update